# Python: поток запускается без команды запуска

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

При запуске следующего кода стартует поток, который запускает функцию (Вывод программы: "Function" ). Но команды  tmp.start() не было. Как это возможно? Python 3.8.2

```
import threading


def func():
    print("Function")


tmp = threading.Thread(target=func())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вызываете `func`, передавая не её объект параметром `target`, а её результат (`None`):

```py
threading.Thread(target=func())
#                           ^^
```

*Аналогично (только в Вашем случае):*

```py
func()
threading.Thread(target=None)
```

---

Передавайте именно объект, не вызывая его:

```py
threading.Thread(target=func)
```